# How to print a javascript value in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

**Description:**
I took a spinning wheel code from Github and edited it and created 2 spinning wheels.
The thing is that when the wheel stops and chooses a number (or letter) it displays it as an alert // alert(value); //. I would like to know how to print the number under the wheel instead of showing it as an alert.  I tried document.body.textContent += value; // but it
displays the result on another blank page instead. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="src/rouletteWheel.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(thisis){
         
            var itemsToShow = 100;
            var wheel = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]
            var items = {};
            for(var i=0; i < itemsToShow; i++){
                items[i] = wheel[i]
            }
           $('#canvas').rouletteWheel({
             items : items,
             selected : function(key, value){
              alert(value);
              
             },
             spinText : 'Ticket Number',
           });
         
           
         
         });
      </script>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body style="background-color:black;"  ></body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="740" height="740"></canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('body').append('<div>'+value+'</div>')`

Comment: That solved it! thank you.
instead, i put $('footer') and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the number under the wheel you had to create an html element inside body tag of your web page, for example

```
 <p id="show_alert_value_p"></p>
```

than in your Js code add this line instead of alert

```
     $('#canvas').rouletteWheel({
         items : items,
         selected : function(key, value){

          //alert(value);
          //comment alert and add below line

          $('#show_alert_value_p').html(value);
          
         },
         spinText : 'Ticket Number',
       });
```

Comment: thank you for helping me out, i used your code and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify or create a HTML element that will hold the value of said wheel.
Something along the lines of...

```
<div>
<h3> Results are: </h3>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
</div>
```

And instead of the alert function use something like.

```
$("#result").text(value)
```

Overall you should be more specific in you question description and making your script runnable in from of a snippet would help people find a answer for you.

Comment: @AliHamdar Mind upvoting it or selecting it as the correct answer so you can close the question.